# Точка входа на сайт

Tags: apache, xampp

Использую xampp(настройки по умолчанию). В корне проекта .htaccess c кодом:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1﻿
```

В папке public .htaccess c кодом:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L, QSA]
```

Задача создать точку входа на проект.

Получаю Error 404. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php

Может пригодится